# I have problems with internet connectivity in fedora 17 GNOME

Tags: internet-connection, fedora-17

I am new to Linux!Fedora is my first try.But i fail to understand why i have problems in using internet with my installed fedora!!I have no problems surfing with the live image(as a LIVE SYSTEM USER) even on windows 7 internet connectivity is not an issue.The BSNL person from BSNL had fixed the issue by replacing google dns by bsnl dns.But when i reinstalled fedora(had lost windows 7 menu from grub) internet never worked.I have some screenshots of my system Running LIVE [here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Uc3O5lxJCI8/UKOXMjp9VeI/AAAAAAAAAJ4/cYPoJqO-nMo/s800/net%2520with%2520live%2520user.png) Earlier I could connect to my modem via opera by 192.168.1.1 But now i can't.Even windows/fedora LIVE doesn't load this page.I had posted this question at [askFedoraProject](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/2674/problems-with-internet-connetivity) also but after reinstalling fedora 17 everything is in a mess!Is this problem common in all LINUX distros or it is a fedora bug.Which distro has FEWER problems?I will soon upload a screenshot of my installed FEDORA 17.please see my comment @ [askFedoraProject]